# Newspaper space allocation for news and advertisment

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, html5, jquery

I need to develop a online system for a local newspaper for allocate their daily advertisements and news on each page of the newspaper. They have more than 5 persons to get advertisements from customer, and also they have some agents in other area of the district. So when one person allocate the space for an advertisement it should be updated instantly to all agents page, and prevent to duplicate allocation. Is there any open source software for this purpose in PHP, or any other language?

Comment: Are you looking for specific scripts or simply a framework or CMS to work with?

Comment: The task in question can be accomplished through *any* efficient communications medium which informs the agents (telephone, e-mail, instant messaging, Google Docs).